# Find month and year for which bill is not generated for particular customer

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables, one is `Customer`, another is `bill`.

- Columns for `customer` are `custID`, `name`.
- Columns for `Bill` are `custID`, `month`, `year`, `amount`

Every time a bill is generated, an entry is made into the `bill` table for that particular customer with `custId`. For every month there is a bill for customer but generation of bill is manual.

Now at particular month I want to find out that how many bills are not yet generated for particular customer.

I am java developer and new to SQL so I don’t have any idea about it.

Database : SQLite3

Thanks in advance.

I have tried:

```
select Customer.mCustomerId, Bill.Month,Bill.Year 
from Customer 
left outer join 
Bill on Customer.mCustomerId = Bill.mCustomerId
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @Rohit 'select Customer.mCustomerId, Bill.Month,Bill.Year from Customer left outer join Bill on Customer.mCustomerId = Bill.mCustomerId' hence this query gives me all customer and bills month and year of bill for that customer. now i want month and year for customer till current month for which bill entry is not made

Comment: That SQL gives all customers regardless of whether they were ever billed. That's not what you want. You need a calendar or tally table. Do you have a table which lists ever possible billing month? you need to outer join to that. If yuo don't you can generate one on the fly. Do you have an Oracle client tool to test these things out?

Comment: Thnx @Nick.McDermaid for your responce... and edit....  i need this query  for android app and usign Sqlite database. can i use oracle client for sqlite? and i can generate all the possible month and year for billing but some time last month may not listed in that so can you give me hint in this scenario how can i got my required result

Comment: As per my prior comment: Do you have a table which lists every possible billing month? Y/N?

Comment: Sorry for some reason I thought you tagged Oracle. So forget about Oracle.

Comment: yes it is possible to get all possible month and year for which bill is generated by queering distinct month and year to bill table, but again in such case it possible that for any month not a single bill is generated means bill is not generated for all user but in query result this month and year will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming that, every month a bill entry is generated for that month and for a customer and amount is null or entered manually, you can find for a customer , which months' bills are generated but amount is null:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Bill b ON c.custid = b.custid WHERE c.custid = 1 AND b.amount  IS NULL
```

But if you want to find how many months are missing for a customer in a year, this query returns the missing number of months:

```
SELECT (12 - COUNT(b.month)) FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Bill b ON c.custid = b.custid WHERE c.custid = 1 AND b.year = '2015'
```

I hope those queries will help you

Have a nice day

Comment: The entry of bill made only when bill generate for particular customer by his vendor through provided interface. but in some case his vendor may not created the bill for customer or had forget to generate the bill for customer and this may happen many time. at one place i want to show list of month and year to vendor  for which bill is not generated for particular customer. i think this gives you brief idea about my problem.

Comment: ın that case you should store months by number and select months, years for desired customer, then calculate missing months according to the selected months programmatically. For example if you selected months 1, 3, 5,6,7,8,9,10 in 2015 for a customer , the missing months are 2,4,11,12